# Background processes continue after removing children

Tags: actionscript-3, removechild

I made this menu that launches at the start-up of my program.
(`Main.as`: launches `mainMenu.as`, `mainMenu.as`: launches other instances inside itself.) This `mainMenu` has a button on top which says "new game", I want this button to take me to the next menu, thus removing the `mainMenu`-instance.

I did successfully remove the `mainMenu`. However, I reveiled by using `trace()` inside one of my classes that a function was still running in the background. (This was the class of an instance inside the `mainMenu`-instance).

I have tried both to eliminate the `mainMenu`-instance by using:

```
this.parent.removeChild(this);
trace("all processes shall now be over");
```

and, by removing all the children inside `mainMenu` by using:

```
while (this.numChildren > 0) {
    this.removeChildAt(0);
}
trace("there shall be nothing going on after this");
```

This has removed all the visual stuff from the screen. But a timer-loop-function from one of the instances inside `mainMenu` is still running in the background, once again reviled by `trace()`. All these children should be eliminated at this point, so how come these processes are still running? This noobie needs help.

Comment: Make sure to remove all event listeners on the mainmenu and inside of it before removing the menu itself. If there are any active event listeners the objects will benot garbage collected. Or use weak references when adding event listeners (there is an optional flag for that in the addEventListener method)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Removing an object from the display list doesn't instantly force it to be garbage collected.  Any timers you have defined will keep firing until they're stopped or garbage collected.

You can read more on this topic by searching for "flex memory management" or "actionscript 3 memory management".

Regarding your specific menu example, update your code as follows:

Your menu class and children of the menu class should all implement an interface "ITimerUser" which specifies a "stopTimers" function - it will look something like this:

```
public function stopTimers():void {
    //If there is a timer defined
    this.myTimer.stop();
    this.myTimer = null;
}
```

Then change your removal code to look like this (n.b. if you have non-timer users mixed in, make the `stopTimers` call optional):

```
while (this.numChildren > 0) {
    var child = (ITimerUser) this.getChildAt(0);
    if (child) {
        child.stopTimers();
    }
    this.removeChildAt(0);
}
this.stopTimers();
this.parent.removeChild(this);
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I will definitely look more into interfaces. Being the control freak that I am, I find it frustrating that you can't have total control of the memory management in as3. Well, I guess I will just have to learn how to work around the garbage collector.

I am new to programming in general, and thought maybe I could just erase all data related to a specific class from memory all together. Well then, now I am starting to see part of the struggle.

Comment: @T.Alexander even in a non managed language, being displayed or not is separate from existing in memory. To add to this answer: there's no need to set the timer to `null` if it's just a class member in order to make the object it's a part of eligible for garbage collection.

Comment: @null Good point.  Setting variables to `null` is a (maybe bad) habit I developed when struggling with objects being pinned in modular Flex applications; it's not strictly necessary here.

Comment: @Brian One last question, what are the benefits of making an interface solely for handling timers? Wouldn't a general 'elimination' interface be simpler in this case. (If the inner classes have timers, then include them in the removal process). I ask this out of inexperience.

Comment: The interface is just useful to guarantee that you'll have the `stopTimers` function available.  If you have any other similar needs, a more general `Elimination` or `Disposable` interface would definitely make sense.